# How to put the code to docker image while building

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to clone the code to docker image while building it

I am thinking to pass the ssh keys while git clone, which is not working. below is the command i am using, showing permission denied

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub my keys;  git clone ssh://git@location.git'
```

I can't use the cloning using https

ALSO say if the code is cloned on image, CAN WE GIT PULL WHILE RUNNING IT ON CONTAINER

Comment: Unless you are trying to create a build environment, including git inside the container is usually not a good practice. And no, you cannot pull on a running container. Those images are immutable after built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are two real paradigms here:

1. I am working on my local machine.
   In this scenario, you more than likely already have the code checked out onto your local machine. Here, just use the COPY directive to take the entire folder and put it somewhere into the container. No need to worry about git or anything of the sort.
2. I am having a build server perform the build
   In this scenario, it makes sense to let the build server check the code out and then perform the same action as above. We just copy the checked out code into the image

Lastly, another alternative that works for dynamic languages like PHP, JS etc, is to NOT put the code into the image, but MOUNT the code onto the container at runtime.

Let's take PHP for example. If the webserver is looking in /var/www/html for the code, you can run your image like this:

```
docker run -d --name {containername} -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /my/dir/where/code/is:/var/www/html {your base image}
```

The above will create the image, but will pass your local directory through to the /var/www/html directory, meaning any changes you make locally would appear in the source code for the container. This was much more prominently used back with Vagrant and the early days of docker before composer was stable.

Answer (score 1):

I Think the way to do is

in your build machine

1. `git clone <repo>`
2. `git archive --format=tar.gz <commit_hash/branch> --output=code.tar.gz`
3. `docker build`

in the Dockerfile you'll have to add

```
ADD code.tar.gz <directory>
```

This will make sure that you're not adding any .git stuff into your container and it'll be small in size as possible.